# Is diffirentiability in finite dimensional space is equivalent to the existence of partial derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be a continuous mapping, defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$. I want to prove that $f$ is differentiable at a point $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ : Is it sufficient to prove that $f$ has first order derivative at $a$ and $b$ i.e $f_x(a,b)$ and $f_y(a,b)$ exists (since we have a finite dimensional space)?

Is there a reference book I could look at to find such result ?

Comment: Not true an any book multi-variable calculus has counter-examples.

Comment: If you add that the partials are continuous at $(a,b)$ it does become true, but without continuity it is not. Be careful though, the inverse does not hold.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks for the additional hypothesis

Comment: Relations: (partial derivatives exist and are continuous) $\Longrightarrow$ (differentiable) $\Longrightarrow$ (partial derivatives exist).  Neither of these can be reversed.

Comment: @GEdgar So we can have existence of partial derivatives but not continuous and the mapping still be differentiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll have hard time to prove what you want... as it is wrong.

A counterexample is $g : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$

$$g(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} & (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\
0 & (x,y) =(0,0)
\end{cases}$$ which has partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ at that point but is not differentiable there.

More [here](https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/differentiability-multivariable-real-functions-part1/).

Comment: Even better, this has all *directional* derivatives at the origin.  If you just want partials, @copper.hat's [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3983393) is probably simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Define $f(x) = \min(x_1,x_2)$ for $x\ge 0$ and zero otherwise.
$f$ is not differentiable at zero but the partials exist at $x=0$.

Answer (score -1):

$f$ might even fail to be continuous at $(a,b)=(0,0)$ :
$$
f(x,y)=\left\{
\matrix{
0, & \text{ if } x=0 \text{ or } y=0,\hfill\cr
1, & \text{ if } x\neq0 \text{ and } y\neq0.
}
\right.
$$

Comment: @sharp, please check the statement of the question.  Only the partial derivatives at $(a,b)$ are required to exist!

Comment: Ah, I misread "a point" as "any point" I see, thanks.