# How to reconcile two definitions of the gradient (partial derivative vs Frechet derivative)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-analysis, definition, vector-analysis

There are two definitions of the gradient of a function $f$ at $x$

1. Stacked partial derivatives of $f$
   $$ \nabla f(x) = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}, ..., \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\right)(x)$$
2. The Frechet derivative

$$
    \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x) - v^Th}
    {\|h\|} = 0
$$
The unique vector $v$ is the gradient of $f$ at $x$.

How can I reconcile between these two definitions? It is not obvious to me that this vector $v$ must be the stacked partial derivatives of $f$.

Can someone help?

Comment: If you take the limit to exist, then it must exist no matter which direction you approach it from. Start picking directions along the axes of $\Bbb{R^n}$ and take the limits. Each direction will decompose to the definition of the partial derivative.

Comment: When the second one exists it's equal to the first one; take $h$ to be a vector pointing in one of the coordinate directions and tending to zero.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks, so when does the second one not exist? I'm a bit confused as to which one I should use as my definition of the gradient.

Comment: Use the second one. The first one is not well-behaved when the second one doesn't exist: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3971029/232

Comment: Meaning of well-behaved?

Comment: The gradient from the second definition tells you a lot about the function's behavior: that it's continuous, that all directional derivatives exist, which of them is largest (the one in direction $v$), things like that. This makes it well-behaved. The gradient from the first definition tells you exactly none of these things. Essentially, nothing interesting can be deduced from its existence (except if it's also continuous, in which case the existence of the second version follows, which *is* interesting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second definition if you take $h=(h_1,0,..,0)$ and let $h_1 \to 0$ you see immediately that $v_1=\frac {\partial f} {\partial x_1}$. Similarly, $v_i=\frac {\partial f} {\partial x_i}$ for all $i$.

However, the existence of partial derivatives does not guarantee the existence of Frechet derivative. For counter-examples see [Is diffirentiability in finite dimensional space is equivalent to the existence of partial derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3983384/is-diffirentiability-in-finite-dimensional-space-is-equivalent-to-the-existence)

Comment: I am not totally sure what you meant by "however". Do you have an example illustrating this?

Comment: I have edited the answer. @Norman

Comment: Thank you. Could you have a Frechet derivative without partial derivative?

Comment: @Norman The arguement I gave in the first part of my answer shows that if the Frechet derivative exists then the partial derivatives will exist.